# Marionette: pass data from CollectionView to ItemView to ItemView

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

Using the structure below, I successfully pass data from a CollectionView to an ItemView. But when I try to pass the same data to a sub-ItemView (and render the data), the data object is undefined.

Any ideas? Below is the code for one method I've tried.

```
var myView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    itemView: myItemView,

    initialize: function(options) {
        this.model = options.model;
    },
    itemViewOptions: function(model,index){
        return{
            viewModel: this.model
        }
    }

});

var myItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: _.template(Template),

    initialize: function(options) {
        this.viewModel = options.viewModel;
    },

    onRender: function(options) {
            // I thought the line below was a method for passing options from one ItemView into another.
        var view = new mySecondItemView ({model: this.viewModel});
        view.render();

        var temp = this.$el["0"]['innerHTML'];
            // The line below proves to my satisfaction that the ItemView is receiving the data model from the CollectionView
        temp += this.viewModel.get("property_name");
        this.$el["0"]['innerHTML'] = temp;
    }
});


var mySecondItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

        // And I thought I could set the viewModel in this function by assigning it the value of the model that was passed through the options.
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.viewModel = options.model;
    },

        // Finally I expect to be able to display information from the data model in the following way. The line below is what tips me off the the fact that viewModel in this second, sub-ItemView is undefined.
    template: _.template('<p><%= this.viewModel.get("property_name") %></p>')
});
```

Comment: How come a CollectionView don't have a collection but a model only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the code below, I gain access to properties of the model in the sub-ItemView by stating merely the property name, so instead of `this.model.get("property_name")`, I can just write `<%= property_name %>`.

```
var myView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({ /* Nothing changes here */ });

var myItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: _.template(Template),

    initialize: function(options) {
        this.viewModel = options.viewModel;
    },

    onRender: function(options) {
            // This does indeed pass the data to the sub-ItemView
        var view = new mySecondItemView ({model: this.viewModel});
        view.render();

        var temp = this.$el["0"]['innerHTML'];
            // The line below pulls the HTML rendered in the sub-ItemView
        temp += '<div class="content">'+view.$el['0']['innerHTML']+'</div>';
        this.$el["0"]['innerHTML'] = temp;
    }
});


var mySecondItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

        // Display a property like so...
    template: _.template('<p><%= property_name %></p>')
});
```